# Anki icon in launcher doesn't work and cant uninstall

Tags: 22.04, anki

A while ago I installed Anki, and it worked for a day and then stopped. I don't remember how I installed it. But the icon exists on my application launcher and does not exist in my in `/usr/share`

`snap list | grep -i anki` shows nothing.

Here is output of `sudo apt-get remove anki`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'anki' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
```

How do I remove this non-working app?

Comment: If you do not know how you installed it who does? Each install method has it own remove method.

Comment: Thank you, this comment added a lot of value.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for all `.desktop` files since I see Anki in Ubuntu Software Manager and these `.desktop` files tell Ubuntu Software Manager what apps to display:

```
sudo find / -iname "*anki*.desktop" 2>/dev/null

/home/.../.local/share/flatpak/app/net.ankiweb.Anki/x86_64/stable/431478bed56ecbe10f86f1df97bfd78ff3417ab73db8928ad0ef8f65e7f25701/files/share/applications/net.ankiweb.Anki.desktop
/home/.../.local/share/flatpak/app/net.ankiweb.Anki/x86_64/stable/431478bed56ecbe10f86f1df97bfd78ff3417ab73db8928ad0ef8f65e7f25701/export/share/applications/net.ankiweb.Anki.desktop
/home/.../.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/applications/net.ankiweb.Anki.desktop
ls /home/.../.local/share/flatpak/app/net.ankiweb.Anki/x86_64/stable/431478bed56ecbe10f86f1df97bfd78ff3417ab73db8928ad0ef8f65e7f25701/files/share/applications/net.ankiweb.Anki.desktop
```

The install was clearly flatpak so I used `flatpak uninstall anki`

Now it is successfully uninstalled